# Add id to body of index.rst in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

To customize a certain page in my documentation, I'd like to add a special class or id to the body of the page.

I've tried using

```
:name: amazing-unique-id;
```

at the top of my index.rst file, but this doesn't work. Any idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: If you mean adding a class or id to the `<body>` tag, then you must edit your Sphinx theme. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html

Comment: Well, I'd like only a certain page to have this class. Not each page in general.

Comment: Use your Jinja2 magic to detect a variable that you use in an option when invoking `make html` to conditionally add the class/id.